# Pascal/Fibonacci and Combinatorics notation

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, combinations

I'm doing Pascal's Triangle and there are a ton of questions related to Pascal and the Fibonacci numbers embedded in the triangle, but I have a question about combinatorics which is most likely a very simple and trivial question.  I derived the Fibonacci numbers using the triangle and combination notation and figured out that
$$F_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}\binom{n-k}{k}$$
But all other formulae I see just replaces my upper bound with $n$.  And thus, a much nicer formula is
$$F_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-k}{k}$$
Ultimately this happens because at some point, $n-k \lt k$ and so you can't have say, 3 choose 4.  Or can you?  Is it really as simple as saying "there are $0$ ways to choose $4$ from $3$" and thus, whenever $n-k \lt k$, $\binom{n-k}{k}=0$?  I always thought that it was undefined, but never really pondered it, or checked old texts to see if this situation was even mentioned.  I thought my "floored" upper bound was neat because it removes the cases mentioned above, but I suppose it's cleaner with just $n$...

Comment: 1. Please check your formulas, the binomials appear incorrect.  2. It is common to extend ${n\choose k}$ to be zero if $k<0$.  3. It is definitely true that ${n\choose k}=0$ if $n,k$ are integers with $k>n$.

Comment: Oh, the bottom should be $k$, not $n$.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s quite customary to define $\binom{m}k=0$ for $k>m$ and for $k<0$, so you could in fact just as well say simply

$$F_n=\sum_k\binom{n-k}k\;:$$

all of the unwanted terms are $0$ anyway. Some define $\binom{m}k$ only for non-negative integers $k$, and then you do have to impose the lower limit of $0$ and the upper limit of $n$ on the summation.

Comment: For your last comment, yeah, it's late and definitely a typo...i fixed it.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Christopher: You’re welcome. (Comment removed now.)